# ORMLite's createOrUpdate seems slow - what is normal speed?

Tags: android, performance, ormlite

Calling the ORMLite `RuntimeExceptionDao`'s `createOrUpdate(...)` method in my app is very slow.

I have a very simple object (`Item`) with a 2 ints (one is the `generatedId`), a `String` and a `double`. I test the time it takes (roughly) to update the object in the database (a 100 times) with the code below. The log statement logs:

> time to update 1 row 100 times: 3069

Why does it take 3 seconds to update an object 100 times, in a table with only 1 row. Is this the normal ORMLite speed? If not, what might be the problem?

```
RuntimeExceptionDao<Item, Integer> dao =
    DatabaseManager.getInstance().getHelper().getReadingStateDao();
Item item = new Item();
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    item.setViewMode(i);
    dao.createOrUpdate(item);
}
long update = System.currentTimeMillis();
Log.v(TAG, "time to update 1 row 100 times: " + (update - start));
```

If I create 100 new rows then the speed is even slower.

Note: I am already using `ormlite_config.txt`. It logs `"Loaded configuration for class ...Item"` so this is not the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This may be the "expected" speed unfortunately.  Make sure you are using ORMLite version 4.39 or higher.  `createOrUpdate(...)` was using a more expensive method to test for existing of the object in the database beforehand.  But I suspect this is going to be a minimal speed improvement.

> If I create 100 new rows then the speed is even slower.

By default Sqlite is in auto-commit mode.  One thing to try is to wrap your inserts (or your `createOrUpdate`s) using the the [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) `Dao.callBatchTasks(...)` method.

In by [BulkInsertsTest android unit test](http://ormlite.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ormlite/ormliteAndroidTest/src/com/j256/ormlite/android/BulkInsertTest.java?view=markup), the following `doInserts(...)` method inserts 1000 items.  When I just call it:

```
doInserts(dao);
```

It takes 7.3 seconds in my emulator.  If I call using the `callBatchTasks(...)` method which wraps a transactions around the call in Android Sqlite:

```
dao.callBatchTasks(new Callable<Void>() {
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        doInserts(dao);
        return null;
    }
});
```

It takes 1.6 seconds.  The same performance can be had by using the `dao.setSavePoint(...)` method.  This starts a transaction but is not as good as the `callBachTasks(...)` method because you have to make sure you close your own transaction:

```
DatabaseConnection conn = dao.startThreadConnection();
Savepoint savePoint = null;
try {
    savePoint = conn.setSavePoint(null);
    doInserts(dao);
} finally {
    // commit at the end
    conn.commit(savePoint);
    dao.endThreadConnection(conn);
}
```

This also takes ~1.7 seconds.

Comment: Thanks! The callBatchTasks method makes it a lot faster, it makes the speed alright, if not perfect. 300 ms will result in a small hickup when the user is scrolling (I'm guessing). The only solution to that is moving it into a seperate thread?

Comment: Moving to a separate thread, if you can indeed do it in the background, will certainly not block the UI.  You might try it @Frank.

Comment: On a sidenote to this, the [documentation](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html#index-callBatchTasks) shows an invalid (old?) syntax in the example for `callBatchTasks` (first parameter is ConnectionSource).