# ORMlite object creation with ForeignCollectionField

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I'm new to Ormlite integration but managed to make it work on a learning project (android app)

The issue that I'm facing is a performance + conceptual one .

I'm using Jackson to get a list of Center objects then use ORMLite to persist everything into DB .

My Center object has two ForeignCollectionField , my annotations are correct and with the above code I can get a correct "join" of the wastes that this center can handle and the nature of the center it self .

I can check my DB using an sqlite editor and it seems fine.

The problem is that it takes about 8mn to populate the data base with the 4000objects which is a bit long .

Here is a portion of the code used in my asyncTask(this code works well)

```
Center[] c = new Center[0];
//fill c with Center objects from jackson OK
assert pCenterDao != null;

for(final Center center : c) {
    try {
        pCenterDao.create(center);

        for (CenterTypesItem typesItem : center.getCenterTypesCollection()) {
            CenterTypesItem centerTypesItem = new CenterTypesItem(typesItem.getId(),center);
            pCenterTypesItemDao.createOrUpdate(centerTypesItem);
        }

        for (CenterWastesItem wastesItem : center.getWastesCollection()) {
            CenterWastesItem centerWasteItem = new CenterWastesItem(wastesItem.getId(),center);
            pCenterWastesItemDao.createOrUpdate(centerWasteItem);
        }

        count = pCenterDao.countOf();
        publishProgress(count, Long.valueOf(c.length));

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        result = false ;
    }

    if (isCancelled()){
        result = false ;
        break;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have two FOR loops inside a main FOR loop (not very clever) , can you please tell me how to optimize and correct this .
@Gray please help :)
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use callBatchTasks method. It permit to improve the speed.

You have a good explication here :

[ORMLite's createOrUpdate seems slow - what is normal speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761472/ormlites-createorupdate-seems-slow-what-is-normal-speed?lq=1)

and a good example here :

[Android ORMLite slow create object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749209/android-ormlite-slow-create-object?rq=1)