# is there any delay time to insert data using Ormlite

Tags: android, ormlite

I have an Android app and in my login activity I get my data from a webservice and insert it into sqlite database and in my main activity I select this data from the database.

My problem is the first time I use use the app the list will be empty

I debugged the app and when I keep small amount of time between the login and the main activity , it works well but when I run it fast the list will be empty

I supposed that there is a delay from Ormlite library , I don't know maybe I am wrong

How can I solve this problem  ?

Note: I used Async task to read data from the web-service and in the post execute method I inserted the data into the database then I called my main activity using intent

Comment: Delays in asynchronous tasks are normal. You have to handle it in the UI by presenting the user with a progress icon or message while your list is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I supposed that there is a delay from Ormlite library , I don't know maybe I am wrong

The amount of time that it will take ORMLite to update the database is directly proportional to the amount of data being changed.  If you are adding a large number of rows then you should consider doing it as a batch using the `Dao.callBatchTasks(...)` method.

See here for more details: [ORMLite's createOrUpdate seems slow - what is normal speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761472/ormlites-createorupdate-seems-slow-what-is-normal-speed/11762104#11762104)

Answer (score 1):

DB operations especially multiple one take there time. That is also somewhere stated in the ORM documentation. So it is the right way to use AsyncTask to do this. I would argue to fill the database not on the post execute method but in the `doInBackground` method like your WebService call. Ensure to use a [WeakReference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to the ORM-DB-Connector. Furthermore, give the user a hint about the progress using a combination of [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.htm).

Comment: I put the code in doInBackground  and I still have the same problem

Comment: when I use in  onPostExecute Thread.sleep(2000); the problem will be solved , but I don't want to do that

Comment: Note : I am not using WeakReference

Comment: Thats interessting. Do you check the return values of the insert operation? ORM usually provides you something like the number of rows updated during an operation. Use this to show the user the progress and as flag whether the operations where finished successfully. Finally, you will have an intent that depends on the actual operation state and gets only fired when the operation are finished.